# How to split a key/value with a similar key in value?

Tags: logstash, key-value, logstash-configuration

Please help.

There is such a line in the log

```
Host = hostname SomeApp = AppName SomeMessage = Data[result = ABCD-123456@sip.site.com,1,2,,0,,,sip:user@user.sip.site.com;transport=tcp;host-sip=1;media-service=media,00ABCDEF01234567890,media,0]
```

For division by key:values I use

```
kv {
trim_key => "\s"
value_split => "="
   }
```

And I get the output

```
"Host": "hostname",
"SomeApp": "AppName",
"SomeMessage": "Data[result",
"ABCD-123456@sip.site.com,1,2,,0,,,sip:user@user.sip.site.com;transport": "tcp;host-sip=1;media-service=media,00ABCDEF01234567890,media,0]",
```

How to write a rule to get?

```
"Host": "hostname",
"SomeApp": "AppName",
"SomeMessage": "Data[result = ABCD-123456@sip.site.com,1,2,,0,,,sip:user@user.sip.site.com;transport": "tcp;host-sip=1;media-service=media,00ABCDEF01234567890,media,0]",
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. That gives me nightmares.

**IF** you can trust that the `SomeMessage` field is always the last one on the line, you can fake it with Grok.

```
# This populates the SomeMessage field, and creates a new field
# called `clipped_message` for later use with kv {}
grok {
  match => {
    message => "^{DATA:clipped_message} SomeMessage = %{GREEDYDATA:SomeMessage}$"
  }
}

kv {
  source => "clipped_message"
  trim_key => "\s"
  value_split => "="
}
```

This is very format dependent. The first grok filter populates the tricky field and clips it entirely out of processing by placing the string before it in a new field. The `kv {}` later parses the clipped string, which should populate your other fields.

Comment: And if there are still a couple after this field?
And all keys begin with the prefix Alarm.

Comment: @Dmitry You're now out of the easy answers and into the `ruby {}` filter where you write Ruby code to handle it. It can be done, but I don't trust myself to provide that answer.